# php-mysql left join table last data

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT C.*, cs.name as status_name, ICR.status, ICR.message
FROM customer C
LEFT JOIN customer_status AS cs ON cs.cname = C.status
LEFT JOIN requests as ICR ON ICR.id = (
    SELECT ICRM.customer_id FROM requests ON ICRM 
    WHERE ICRM.customer_id = C.id 
    ORDER BY ICRM.id DESC 
    LIMIT 1 )
WHERE {$whereDate} {$Query}
GROUP BY C.id ORDER BY C.date_add ASC LIMIT 6
```

this line is causing the error

```
LEFT JOIN requests as ICR ON ICR.id = (SELECT ICRM.customer_id FROM requests ON ICRM WHERE ICRM.customer_id = C.id ORDER BY ICRM.id DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

When I add the reques table the data is not working. I want to pull only the last data for each customer from the questions table.

Comment: What is `FROM requests on ICRM` supposed to mean? `ON` can only be used in a `JOIN` clause to specify the relationship between the tables being joined.

Comment: And what is the `ICRM` table? It's never mentioned in any `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to get the last row for each customer from a table.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id, message MAX(id) id FROM requests Group by id)  ICR ON  C.id = ICR.customer_id`  edited but not working